# Extracting texts from Selenium WebElement

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I'm trying to get all the names of the perfumes on [this page](https://www.beaute-test.com/parfums_femme.php)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

But when I try to get the text of the web element attribute I get nothing. In fact, I tried en colaboratory:

```
!pip install selenium
!apt-get update # to update ubuntu to correctly run apt install
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
wd.get("https://www.beaute-test.com/parfums_femme.php")
media_content = wd.find_elements_by_class_name("bt__media__content")
```

En `media_content` we have several elements:

```
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="18f3eed8343ccf0c22fc5c7bae48cff7", element="3123e486-a978-4113-b359-c3e9a89c7e95")>,
 <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="18f3eed8343ccf0c22fc5c7bae48cff7", element="4a7b2d4e-0179-4957-ab32-8f37470bc694")>,
 <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="18f3eed8343ccf0c22fc5c7bae48cff7", element="a7fb478d-aa55-46b8-8953-a7b4dd84220e")>,...
]
```

But this one does not return anything:

```
>>>media_content[1].get_attribute('text')
''
>>>media_content[1].text
''
```

I also tried using the xpath directly on one name I wass looking for but it returns nothing as well.

So how do I get the text of a WebElement ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display all 25 of the names do the following.

```
media_content=wd.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[class='bt__media__content']>p>a>b")
for media in media_content:
    print (media.text)
```

I also used to click on the agree popup.

```
WebDriverWait(wd, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "didomi-notice-agree-button"))).click()
```

Outputs

```
Libre
L'Interdit
Madame Glamour Suddenly
Gabrielle
My Way
Eau de Parfum - Alien
Idôle
Good Girl
Coco Noir
Scandal
Mon Guerlain
Mon Rouge!
Black Opium Eau de Parfum
Mauboussin à La Folie
Black Orchid
Voce Viva
La Nuit Trésor
Eau de Parfum - La Vie est Belle
Chloé Eau de Parfum
Eau de Parfum - La petite Robe noire
Suddenly Diamonds
Mon Paris Eau de Parfum
La Belle
Hypnotic Poison Eau de Toilette
Allure
```

Answer (score 0):

get_attribute returns html attribute like href, id, class etc.

try this:
media_content[1].text

Answer (score 0):

First off, `text` is not an attribute of the html tag. That's an attribute of the selenium web element, so it should just be `.text`.

However, if that returns an empty string, try selecting the actual element containing the text, `b` in this case, and do either `.text` or `.get_attribute('innerHTML')` (or even `.get_attribute('textContent')`) on it. The `innerHTML` method should work even if `.text` returns empty string

```py
>>> media_content[1].find_element_by_tag_name('b').get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

Or simply do it all at once-

```py
>>> [el.get_attribute('innerHTML') for el in wd.find_elements_by_css_selector(".bt__media__content b")]
```